# Error while lifting a sails.js project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sails.js, waterline

I'm getting this error, which I can't really understand:

```
    info: Starting app...

/Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:98
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../fixtures'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/config/bootstrap.js:23:31
    at wrapper (/Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3592:19)
    at applyInOriginalCtx (/Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:421:80)
    at wrappedCallback (/Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:324:18)
    at success (/Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/switchback/lib/normalize.js:33:31)
    at _switch (/Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/switchback/lib/factory.js:58:28)
    at returnResults (/Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/basic.js:392:9)
    at /Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/basic.js:272:16
    at /Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/operations.js:83:7
    at /Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at Object.async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (/Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:236:30)
    at Object.async.forEach.async.each (/Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:209:22)
    at /Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/operations.js:436:11
    at /Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/operations.js:574:5
    at /Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:52:16
    at Object.async.forEachOf.async.eachOf (/Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:236:30)
    at Object.async.forEach.async.each (/Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:209:22)
    at module.exports._buildChildOpts (/Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/operations.js:464:9)
    at module.exports._execChildOpts (/Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/operations.js:432:8)
    at /Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/query/finders/operations.js:81:10
    at wrapper (/Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/lodash/index.js:3592:19)
    at applyInOriginalCtx (/Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:421:80)
    at wrappedCallback (/Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/lib/waterline/utils/normalize.js:324:18)
    at success (/Users/Sammy/Projects/MyProject/node_modules/waterline/node_modules/switchback/lib/normalize.js:33:31)
```

Does it have to do with waterline? Is a module missing? What's this "fixtures" module?

Thanks in advance,
Sammy

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something is missing from your node_modules folder.

Try doing an **npm cache clear** and a clean ***npm install***

In your project folder run:

```
npm cache clear && rm -rf node_modules && npm install
```

Hope it helps

Comment: @sammy Please, if this helped, could you please mark as solved? It might help others comming here.